# In Java, how do I see if an object is of the right type to be passed as a method parameter? Especially if the type is a primitive?

Tags: java, reflection, types, primitive

I'm using reflection to call a method in Java. I'd like to see if the value that potentially is to be passed into the method is of the right type before I invoke the method.

My initial idea was to get the class of the parameter via `method.getParameterTypes()` and then compare that type to the type of the object that I'd like to pass in. If it's a subclass, then proceed.

However, this fails on a method that takes a primitive. If I have a method:

```
private void doThing(boolean parp) {}
```

The return value of `getParameterTypes` for this indicates that the type of the parameter is a class  called `boolean` in the `java.base` module. However, I might be wanting to pass in a value which is of type `java.lang.Boolean`, which although is perfectly legal to pass in, doesn't sit in the type hierarchy. `java.lang.Boolean` isn't a subclass of, or apparently in any way related to `boolean`.

What test can I use against a method's given parameter type and the type of a given object to determine whether its legal to pass that object into the method?

Comment: You need use pure java, or can use library for resolve that

Comment: The Boolean object can be null, boolean cannot. This applies for int, double and float as well. You can try and do something along this concept.

Comment: `MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(method.getReturnType(), method.getParameterTypes()).wrap();`. You still have to create for `null` validity or primitive value widening conversions yourself if you want to support it.

Comment: @Holger nice. Unfortunately my context is Android API21, and this needs 26 :( Good solution though.

Answer (score 2):

Like this, perhaps:

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> primitiveToBoxed = new HashMap<>();
static {
  primitiveToBoxed.put(Boolean.TYPE, Boolean.class);
  primitiveToBoxed.put(Character.TYPE, Character.class);
  primitiveToBoxed.put(Byte.TYPE, Byte.class);
  primitiveToBoxed.put(Short.TYPE, Short.class);
  primitiveToBoxed.put(Integer.TYPE, Integer.class);
  primitiveToBoxed.put(Long.TYPE, Long.class);
  primitiveToBoxed.put(Float.TYPE, Float.class);
  primitiveToBoxed.put(Double.TYPE, Double.class);
  primitiveToBoxed.put(Void.TYPE, Void.class);
}

private static final Map<Class<?>, Set<Class<?>>> allowedConversions = new HashMap<>();
static {
  allowedConversions.put(Short.class, setOf(Byte.class));
  allowedConversions.put(Integer.class, setOf(Byte.class, Character.class, Short.class));
  allowedConversions.put(Long.class, setOf(Byte.class, Character.class, Short.class, Integer.class));
  allowedConversions.put(Float.class, setOf(Byte.class, Character.class, Short.class, Integer.class, Long.class));
  allowedConversions.put(Double.class, setOf(Byte.class, Character.class, Short.class, Integer.class, Long.class, Float.class));
}

static <T> Set<T> setOf(T... elements) {
  return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(elements));
}

static boolean isCompatible(Class<?> type, Object value) {
  if (type.isPrimitive()) {
    if (value == null) {
      return false;
    }
    type = primitiveToBoxed.get(type);
  }
  return value == null || type.isAssignableFrom(value.getClass())
      || allowedConversions.getOrDefault(type, emptySet()).contains(value.getClass());
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... this isn't 100% correct; it gives false negatives for widening conversions allowed by reflection. For example, it's legal to pass an `int` to a method that takes a `long` using reflection, but `isCompatible(Long.TYPE, 1)` erroneously returns `false`.

Comment: Okay, updated to support widening conversions. Whew. IMO you might as well just try to invoke the method and catch the IllegalArgumentException ;-)

Comment: @growse Indeed. I wonder if there is a more elegant way to solve the problem. If you find one, please post a self-answer so we can all benefit.